# Loop over table cells to find closest span text when checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the `span` text when looping over table cells with no success.

```html
<td>
<select name="newStatus" class="stChange">
    <option value="0-596">active</option>
    <option value="2-596">logout</option>
    </select>
  </td>
  
  <td class="CellWithComment">
  <input id="c57"  type="checkbox" name="tfoza" value="1">
  <label for="c57">
  <span></span>
  </label>
  <span class="CellComment">960</span>
  </td>
  
  <td class="CellWithComment">
  <input id="c58"  type="checkbox" name="tfoza" value="1">
  <label for="c58">
  <span></span>
  </label>
  <span class="CellComment">901</span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

jquery:

```js
   $('.stChange').on('change', function () 
{ 

var st = $(this).val();
var vls = st.split('-');

 if( vls[0] == 0){
 console.log('0',st);
            $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function(){
          console.log($(this).find('.CellComment').text())  ;  
      });
 }
 if( vls[0] == 2){
 
 }
 
});
```

I'm trying to find the `span` text when the checkbox is checked ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/canabatz/ad8vyn05/22/)).

What is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line of code `$(this).find('.CellComment').text()` was the problem. The find function looks for children and grand children etc inside of a parent element. That line of code is looking for `.CellComment` inside the checkbox, which the `.each` function is iterating through.

I have change that line of code to `$(this).parent().find('.CellComment').text()`. I have selected the parent of the checkbox using the `parent()` function, which selects the `.CellWithComment` element and then find the `.CellComment` element inside.

```js
$('.stChange').on('change', function (event) 
{ 

  var st = $(this).val();
  var vls = st.split('-');

  if( vls[0] == 0){
    $(event.target).closest('tr').find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
      console.log($(this).parent().find('.CellComment').text());  
    });
   }

  if( vls[0] == 2){

  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="test">
      <select name="newStatus" class="stChange">
        <option value="0-596">active</option>
        <option value="2-596">logout</option>
      </select>
    </td>

    <td class="CellWithComment">
      <input id="c57"  type="checkbox" name="tfoza" value="1">
      <label for="c57">
        <span></span>
      </label>
      <span class="CellComment">960</span>
    </td>

    <td class="CellWithComment">
      <input id="c58"  type="checkbox" name="tfoza" value="1">
      <label for="c58">
        <span></span>
      </label>
      <span class="CellComment">901</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```